# "I have been working..." versus "I have worked..." in response to "Who have you worked with so far?"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, syntactic-analysis

> Q: Who have you worked with so far?
>
> A: I **have been working** with people from all over the world.

The best answer would be 'I **have worked** with people from all over the world'.

One of my students answered like the above. What do you think?  Is this grammatically correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use "have been —ing"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19065/how-to-use-have-been-ing)